# New SQL instance and migration

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration

What are the best practices of creating new SQL Server instance on SQL Server Clustering 2008 R2 and migrating a database with high transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from this list from Jonathan Kehayias.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/03/22/sql-server-installation-checklist.aspx

Can you elaborate on "migrating a database with high transactions"? This is very open ended question and not sure how to address this. There are lot of good practices to follow here.

- Making sure data, logs, tempdb are on separate disk and following best practices for Files i.e Instant file initialization, pre-allocating sizes so that autogrow won't happen, partition alignment, having good RAID http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmymay/archive/tags/disk+partition+alignment/
- Good index creation & maintenance procedures
- Good application + sql code
- Getting a head start on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672789(v=sql.100).aspx
- Having decent memory size so that disk access is limited
- Looking for disk latency using virtual file stats DMV
- Watching for WAIT STATISTICS

There are so many other things here but it takes a while to list them all and it depends.

Comment: +1 from me - I like the last two words. They are exactly the perfect summary of the story :-).